# How to solve Circular dependency error in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

I am executing the following code inside a post request:

```
try{
  const _id = await db.collection('UserInformation').insertOne(userObj);
  await db.collection('LoggedInUser').updateOne({ userId: _id }, { '$set': { 
  'isLoggedIn': true } }, { upsert: true });  
}
catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}
```

and I am getting the circular dependency error.

When I comment out the following line, everything works fine.

```
await db.collection('LoggedInUser').updateOne({ userId: _id }, { '$set': { 
  'isLoggedIn': true } }, { upsert: true });
```

Kindly let me know what may be the issue here and how to rectify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `insertOne()` doesn't return an `_id`, it returns a [`InsertOneWriteOpResult`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#~insertOneWriteOpResult). This has a `connection` field which will likely have circular references.

Use `insertedId` from the result object instead of the whole object itself.